# Extracting a manager's EmployeeID from AD using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

First of all, apologies if this has been asked before but I tried a search and came up blank.

I'm working on a script in PS for HR whereby a users details are extracted from AD to .csv and I'm struggling to extract the user's Manager's EmployeeID.

Before this requirement they were using email address as the unique identifier for each member of staff/manager but now they require the Manager's unique ID instead.

Here's a snippet of the old script which works fine and pulls the managers email, I'd like to pull the manager's EmployeeID instead if possible and add that into the 'approver' column.

```
@{Label = "email";Expression = {$_.EmailAddress.ToLower()}},
@{Label = "first_name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
@{Label = "last_name";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
@{Label = "approver";Expression = {%{(Get-AdUser $_.Manager -server $ADServer -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress.ToLower()}}},
@{Label = "approver2";Expression = {""}},
@{Label = "leaving_date";Expression = {""}},
@{Label = "job_title";Expression = {$_.Title}},
```

Any help would be much appreciated as it's driving me nuts.

Thanks!

Comment: By the looks of it you have already queried the manager's AD object (`$_.Manager`) there is no need to query it again, just add to your question the code that comes before this calculated properties

Comment: You're correct that I am querying the managers AD object but the code above obtains their e-mail address and I'm not sure how to change this to obtain their 'EmployeeID' instead. I have no problem with their email but I can't seem to pull their ID.

Comment: I guess something like `-Properties EmployeeID`

Comment: I did try that one and it returns: CN=Users Name,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXX,OU=XXXXXXXXX,DC=XX instead of the ID

Comment: the right side of the query would be something like `-Properties EmployeeID).EmployeeID`

Answer (score 0):

```
@{n="ManagerName";e={get-aduser $_.manager | select -ExpandProperty name}}, @{n="Manager Employee ID";e={get-aduser $_.manager -properties employeeid | select -ExpandProperty employeeid}} |
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].